# Facebook PHP API: preventing the cookie if not logging in?

Tags: php, facebook, api, session, cookies

I followed the example here -- https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk :

```
require 'php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Great, it gives me a user id for users logging in through Facebook.
However, for users who aren't logged in ($user = 0), it creates a useless cookie and starts a session. Is there some way around this? Why does it create a cookie/start a session for a user who doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is started when the [Facebook object is created](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php#L36). This is specified in constructor documentation.

Apparently, there is no easy workarround.

Comment: The `Facebook` class is created as a sample wrapper over `BaseFacebook`. So OP could extend it or replace

Comment: @zerkms Yes, but will be necessary to implement all the methods that `Facebook` class implements (at moment 4 methods, but if the `BaseFacebook` class get more abstract methods, the subclass will be broken).

Comment: you can extend it and only override the constructor

Comment: Is it possible to override the constructor of `Facebook` calling the constructor of `BaseFacebook`?

Comment: Well, in this case it looks like that is to keep things simpler. Instead of check if the session exists in each method that store things there, the verification is done only once, in the constructor. Are you having problems with this?

Comment: Simpler for Facebook's coding, perhaps. I don't appreciate having an empty session file open because Facebook wanted to keep their API internal coding simpler.